# Nokia QA: The application cannot be launched successfully with an error message 'Application not supported. Delete?'

Tags: java-me, j2mepolish, nokia-s40

My Java s40 app for asha failed the QA test with the above title. I have tried recreating the problem by download the jar file to one of the supported asha phone and the app launched successfully.
Every other things seems okay i have also used the Nokia RDA to test the app. What other reasons may be causing the failure.

Comment: JAD attributes sometimes cause errors like that. Maybe you're not seeing the error because you're just installing the JAR? Try installing OTA (Over The Air) by typing in the URL to the JAD file instead in the phone browser. Maybe you can reproduce the error that way.

Comment: You have to copy both the JAR and JAD file to a webserver of course, before being able to do this. Also make sure MIME-types for JAD and JAR files are set correctly on the webserver.

Comment: i have tried OTA specifying the URL of the JAD file and the error was not reproduced. The app installed and launched correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just from the Error message I can assume that the your Jar File's MIDP & CLDC version doesnt match with your S40 Asha series phone.

You need to open your editor/IDE and change to MIDP Version to 2.0 & CLDC's version to 1.1.

Comment: taken note of that, MIDP version is set to 2.1 will change it to 2.0 as u've specified and re-submit.

Comment: For Nokia QA testing, it usually takes 3-5 business days to get a response. Will wait to get their response. Thanks Lucifer

Comment: Ok, I thought you have Asha Device with you and you are going to test it in. Anyways, lets wait :)

Comment: Of course, i have already tested the app before submitting for QA review, that was before Nokia reply that the application could not be launched successfully. It worked perfectly on my Asha 302 and 305 device. Even when i implemented your suggestion, it's also working. Don't really know why it's not working with the QA team.